# The recipient email does not receive any message in django

Tags: python-3.x, django

I have a web application and I would like to be able to send an automatic email to any user in case of need. I am testing it and everything seems to be fine but I noticed that the recipient email does not receive any message.
Below is my configuration in the `settings.py` file.

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'beaubien.web-dns1.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'med.abdillah@massiwatechnology.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '###########'
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
```

Here is `views.py` file.

```
def send_email(request):
    send_mail('Bonjour cher personnel',
              'Hello there,Ceci est un message automatique.',
              'med.abdillah@massiwatechnology.com',
              ['abdillah@buaa.edu.cn'],
              fail_silently=False,
              )
    return render(request, 'courriers/send_email.html')

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sent!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Send an email!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Please, assist me.
Thank you in advence

Comment: There's a lot of moving parts here. Have you ruled out that isn't not on the client side? What do your logs say when you call `send_email()`?

Comment: @Hayden I have edited my question and added the html code. So if everything is ok the I have to receive the "Send an email!" otherwise fail_silently=False should display the error as I understood. Am I right please? Also, this is the beaubien.web-dns1.com has been given by email hoster.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration was fine but I noticed that the issue was about the recipient's email address. I have changed it and use another email address and now everything is perfect.
Emails to the recipient's email address were getting rejected.

Thank you, guys.